# ASP.NET Web API 2 - [FromBody] is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a really simple test app to send over a json Post to my web services. Everything is working expect for some reason the value received in the `Post([FromBody] string value)` is null.

```
// POST api/<controller>
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] string value)
{
    var tagCall = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.TagCall>(value);
    new CampaignContactService().UpdateCallStatusToPulled(tagCall.DeviceId, tagCall.ccId);

    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent("success", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    return ResponseMessage(response);
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Policy;

namespace TestSandBox
{
    public class TagCall
    {
        public string DeviceId { get; set; }
        public int ccId { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        public static string Result { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TagCall t = new TagCall()
            {
                ccId = 1,
                DeviceId = "apples"
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);

            try
            {
                var result = ReadAsStringAsync("http://localhost:44324/api/CampaignContact", json);
                result.Wait();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        static async Task ReadAsStringAsync(string url, string jsonBody)
        {
            var data = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            using (var c = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    var response = await c.PostAsync(url, data);
                    Result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(Result);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the only thing in my WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
}
```

Comment: Can we see your http request?

Comment: @Sajed If by see, if i post  a debug on the api web service, yes it's getting hit and it's null

Comment: I think you might already be using some serializer/deserializer and you don't need to manually serialize/deserialize: the framework automatically does that, so `string` is not acceptable there, just replace it with the `[FromBody] TagCall` directly. This is just a doubt. Can you post your Startup class, or just the code where you register your controllers. Are you doing a `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();` call?

Comment: Did you try with`TagCall` instead of `string`? Also, are you using camel-casing or no?

Comment: Oh, you should emphasize in your post you are using a Self-Hosted Web API in a console app. I've never done that, but maybe someone knows something. Nevertheless, still follow the above tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `[FromBody] string value` cannot be properly deserialized, as you serialize the object inside `StringContent`. That's why your endpoint tries to deserialize it as an object.

The possible solutions are:

- use `PostAsJsonAsync<string>()` and send your json value:

```
static async Task ReadAsStringAsync(string url, string jsonBody)
{
    using (var c = new HttpClient())
    {
          try
          {
              var response = await c.PostAsJsonAsync(url, jsonBody);
              Result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
              Console.WriteLine(Result);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
          }
    }
}
```

- set input parameter as object instead of string and then cast it to `Model.TagCall`:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] object value)
{
    var jsonValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    var tagCall = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.TagCall>(jsonValue );
    ....
}
```

- as you have access to `Model.TagCall` in your controller, making it an input parameter will be the better choice over here:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Model.TagCall value)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: I went with [FromBody] object value), this will allow me not to change my hosting project.